# How to know if certain function exists and has been called

Tags: function, assembly, x86, label

I've recently started with x86 assembler, but I can't find any method to know if a certain function exists in the code and if it's been called in an execution or not.

For example, I've got a code with a function called "Sum", I need a command or anything that let me know if "Sum" exists in the assembler code and it's been called in an execution.

Thanks in advance
Luthor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to know if a function has been called already or not with making that function set some global memory somewhere to indicate its first use (al la `static` in C). in terms of knowing if it exists, this is also nigh impossible unless the function has an EAT entry, in which case you can use `GetProcAddress` to get the address, and check that it isn't null.

If you want to do this at 'compile' time however, you can tell if a function exists by trying to call it and let the assembler or linker toss an error at you if it doesn't.

With all that being said, it sounds like you should rather be re-evaluating your approach, why exactly do you need to tell if a function has already been called and if it exists or not?

Comment: Luthor here, thanks for your answer. 
It's a question in one of my exercises. It says:
"Explain a practical way of knowing if in an assembly code exists a function called "Hello". Explain how to know if, it it exists, this function is invoked or not."

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just want to see if a function exists in the code, you can Find it in your editor. If you find it, it exists.

As for checking whether it is called - that's a bit trickier because it could be called indirectly, but you could set a breakpoint on its first instruction and debug the code. If the debugger stops, the function is called. If the debugger doesn't stop there, it doesn't mean it's *never* called, though.

Answer (score 0):

To find out if a routine named "Hello" exists, there a few things that can be tried.

From a *nix command line ...

At the top of the project tree, perform "grep -lrw Hello *".  This will return a list of files that contain the word "Hello".  Then, you just have to search those files.

Alternatively, if you have the debugging information compiled into your libraries/object files, you may try "nm  | grep Hello" to determine if there is a routine named "Hello".

Or, you may wish to perform an "objdump -d " and search for a routine/label named "Hello" (also assumes that debugging information is included in the image).

However, many IDE's have built in function finders.  You may be able to use that if you are using one.

As to determining whether or not this routine has been called, that would require setting and checking a global variable at run-time.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've found a way. Gcc compilator has -S option which forces him to make the assembler code, then with a grep you can see it.
About to know if it has been executed, the breakpoint thing worked well so far.

Thanks you guys!